# What is the proper Array declaration for 'var currentSeries' in EPPlus for line charting with multiple series?

Tags: c#, excel, charts, epplus

I wish to create a line chart in EPPlus with multiple series depicted on the chart.
Each of the data series is stored in consecutive rows (iRow) in the worksheet.
I wish to wrap the currentSeries definition in a loop to access each row of data to appear on the line chart
Ideally I would like to declare currentSeries as an array currentSeries[i]

var currentSeries = currentChart.Series.Add(dataWorksheet.Cells[iXaxisSeriesRow, ifirstDataCol, iXaxisSeriesRow, ilastDataCol], dataWorksheet.Cells[iRow, ifirstDataCol, iRow, ilastDataCol]);

Question: How do I declare the var currentSeries as an Array?

================== 2 days later ===========

I solved this. The seed of the solution came from riptutorial.com. I have modified what I found there to assist other morons like me.

The key is:
var range = new List<OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRange>();
even better:
var linechart = new List<OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.ExcelLineChart>();

My example specifically excludes the looping functions so that you can see where to insert the loops and how they will work. The example will be turned into a working method using the linechart list above, but for now here is a working example of how to use list to be able to chart series of data when you do not know how many series you will need to chart, and you want a fully generic charting solution:

Clearly you need to have the excel workbook named "Graphs" in the folder C:_Charts_test. The method creates a worksheet (no checking), populates it with data and plots it. In my real life example I have hundreds of lines of data and I am plotting small random snapshots as and when I find anomalies in the data.

```
public void testChart(){

    string strActiveWorkbook = "C:\\_Charts_test\\Graphs.xlsx";
    FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(strActiveWorkbook);
    using (OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage excelPackage = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(newFile)){
    
    //create a WorkSheet
    OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Example");
    
    //fill cell data with a loop, note that row and column indexes start at 1
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 2; i <= 11; i++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[1, i].Value = "Value " + (i - 1);
        worksheet.Cells[2, i].Value = rnd.Next(5, 25);
        worksheet.Cells[3, i].Value = rnd.Next(5, 25);
        worksheet.Cells[4, i].Value = rnd.Next(5, 25);
        worksheet.Cells[5, i].Value = rnd.Next(5, 25);
    }
    
    worksheet.Cells[2, 1].Value = "Series 1";
    worksheet.Cells[3, 1].Value = "Series 2";
    worksheet.Cells[4, 1].Value = "Series 3";
    worksheet.Cells[5, 1].Value = "Series 4";
    
    //create a new piechart of type Line
    ExcelLineChart lineChart = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart("lineChart", eChartType.Line) as ExcelLineChart;
    
    // var linechart = new List<OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.ExcelLineChart>();
    
    
    //set the title
    lineChart.Title.Text = "LineChart Example";
    
    var range = new List<OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRange>();
           
    //create the ranges for the chart
    var rangeLabel = worksheet.Cells["B1:K1"];
    
    range.Add(worksheet.Cells["B2:K2"]);
    range.Add(worksheet.Cells["B3:K3"]);
    range.Add(worksheet.Cells["B4:K4"]);
    range.Add(worksheet.Cells["B5:K5"]);
    
    //add the ranges to the chart
    lineChart.Series.Add(range[0], rangeLabel);
    lineChart.Series.Add(range[1], rangeLabel);
    lineChart.Series.Add(range[2], rangeLabel);
    lineChart.Series.Add(range[3], rangeLabel);
    
    
    //set the names of the legend
    lineChart.Series[0].Header = worksheet.Cells["A2"].Value.ToString();
    lineChart.Series[1].Header = worksheet.Cells["A3"].Value.ToString();
    lineChart.Series[2].Header = worksheet.Cells["A4"].Value.ToString();
    lineChart.Series[3].Header = worksheet.Cells["A5"].Value.ToString();
    
    //position of the legend
    lineChart.Legend.Position = eLegendPosition.Right;
    
    //size of the chart
    lineChart.SetSize(600, 300);
    
    //add the chart
    lineChart.SetPosition(200,100);
    worksheet.Calculate();
    excelPackage.Save();
    excelPackage.Dispose();
    }
}
```